# discord.py: Problems when reading out several users from a SQLite3 DB

Tags: python, discord, bots, scheduled-tasks, discord.py

I have a problem with a SQLite3 database. My code below works for ONE user.
When it's a user's birthday, my bot checks my database and prints it out.

But some days two or three users have birthdays on the same day.
How can I modify my code so that the bot outputs all possible birthday users?

I tried to solve it with fetchmany (2). Unfortunately this fails if it hits a day where only one user has a birthday.

```
async def bday_check():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    while not bot.is_closed():
        channel = bot.get_channel(1234567890)
        bdaydate = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%d.%m.')
        bdaytime = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%H:%M')
        async with aiosqlite.connect("path/to/my.db") as db:
            c = await db.execute('SELECT * FROM user WHERE birthday = ?',(bdaydate,))
            data = await c.fetchone()
            await db.commit()

        if (bdaydate == data[6]) and (bdaytime == '09:00'):
           messages = f'Happy Birthday {data[0]}.'
           embed = discord.Embed(title=f"**Birthday of {data[0]}**", colour=discord.Colour(0xffffff))
           embed.add_field(name="\u200B", value=messages, inline=False)
           embed.set_thumbnail(url=data[2])
           await channel.send(embed=embed)
           await asyncio.sleep(60)
        else:
           await asyncio.sleep(60)
        

bot.loop.create_task(bday_check())
```

The birthday data is stored in the "user" database in the "birthday" column. There the day and month are in the format dd.mm.

I hope someone can help me here.

Comment: try iterating through the entire list ```data``` like ```for d in data:``` and then match it with ```if d == data[6] and bdaytime == '09:00'``` and see if it works.

Comment: you could use paging with limit and offset https://pastebin.com/2sp0RNDW

Comment: hello and thank you for your help @jyotirmay-kumar-jha and @dave-ankin .
i have modified my code. but now i get these error:
`Traceback (most recent call last): File "bday.py", line 217, in bday_check c = await db.execute('SELECT * FROM user WHERE birthday = ? limit 1 offset ' + offset,(bdaydate,)) TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str.`
The column "birthday" is from type "TEXT"

Comment: `c = await db.execute('SELECT * FROM user WHERE birthday = ? limit 1 offset ' + str(offset),(bdaydate,))` was the solution. Thank you for you help @JyotirmayKumarJha @DaveAnkin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
async def bday_check():
await bot.wait_until_ready()
while not bot.is_closed():
    channel = bot.get_channel(1234567890)
    bdaydate = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%d.%m.')
    bdaytime = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%H:%M')
    rows = []
    async with aiosqlite.connect("path/to/my.db") as db:
        offset = 0
        while True:
            c = await db.execute('SELECT * FROM user WHERE birthday = ? limit 1 offset ' + str(offset),(bdaydate,))
            data = await c.fetchone()
            if data is not None:
                rows.append(data)
                offset += 1
            else:
                break
        await db.commit()

    for data in rows:
        if (bdaydate == data[6]) and (bdaytime == '09:00'):
            messages = f'Happy Birthday {data[0]}.'
            embed = discord.Embed(title=f"**Birthday of {data[0]}**", colour=discord.Colour(0xffffff))
            embed.add_field(name="\u200B", value=messages, inline=False)
            embed.set_thumbnail(url=data[2])
            await channel.send(embed=embed)

    await asyncio.sleep(60)
```

bot.loop.create_task(bday_check())

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using .fetchall() method?

```
async for user in db.exec(xxx).fetchall():
    #do something about the user
```

Also I just noticed, you don't have to call commit everytime if you are not writing to db (INSERT, DELETE or UPDATE)